# Parsing data in dictionary (json) using openweathermap api

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests, openweathermap

I'm still new to Python while exploring, learning, and today I'm working with JSON. How do I parse and print 'dt_txt' key and corresponding value each time it appears in my dictionary? Here is my code.

```
import requests, pytemperature, json

r = requests.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?
lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1')
dict = r.json()

for key, value in dict.items():
    if 'dt_txt' in str(key):
        print(key)
```

Here is JSON snapshot or full content in link above.

```
    {
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.179,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [{
        "dt": 1509202800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 297.18,
            "temp_min": 291.573,
            "temp_max": 297.18,
            "pressure": 1027.02,
            "sea_level": 1029.75,
            "grnd_level": 1027.02,
            "humidity": 68,
            "temp_kf": 5.6
        },
        "weather": [{
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 88
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.61,
            "deg": 99.0033
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.09
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2017-10-28 15:00:00"
    }, {
        "dt": 1509213600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 297.32,
            "temp_min": 293.116,
            "temp_max": 297.32,
            "pressure": 1024.56,
            "sea_level": 1027.16,
            "grnd_level": 1024.56,
            "humidity": 76,
            "temp_kf": 4.2
        },
        "weather": [{
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 48
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.96,
            "deg": 173.002
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.41
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2017-10-28 18:00:00"
```

Side note: In the end I am trying to print the date, temp_min, temp_max, main, and description. I will be converting the temp from kelvin to fahrenheit then using gmail to text message me each day the new forecast. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can all each dict keys by your_dict['your_value'], try this:

```
import requests, json

r = requests.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1')
dict = r.json()
select_data = dict['list']

for box in select_data:

    if 'dt_txt' in box:
        print(box['dt_txt'])

    else:
        print('not found')
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question exactly.

Comment: @MatthewB: so tick my answer plz :)

Comment: I did tick it but stack overflow says I need to have at least 15 reputation points to vote. I'd down vote that rule if I could

Comment: how about now? :)

Comment: It says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly display post score."